# Custom adapter for 3 listviews

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter, custom-adapter, android-tablayout

I have a problem with the app I'm trying to create. I've done lots of googling over the last few days but I can't seem to figure it out.

The goal is to have an expandable list view on one activity, that has a total of 12 options. Each of those 12 options, when clicked, will bring the user to the same layout, which has 3 tabs(named Monday, Wednesday, Friday). Each tab has a listview. This all works for my app so far. Now I want my custom adapter to populate those 3 listviews with different data(that I plan to hardcode into the app, not a ton of data so don't think it will slow it down), depending on what item on the Expandable List View was clicked.

The problem I'm coming across is, I have no idea how I can let the custom adapter know which item on the Expandable ListView was clicked, and I don't know how to take that info, and populate three different listviews in 3 different tabs with three different sets of data..

The data is very straight forward and it's all very similar. Each row will have 3 textboxes, one containing one word and 2 containing numbers. It will also have a checkbox

I've made custom adapters before, but they were for single listviews, and I didn't have to seperate the data, so it was much easier. I have no idea how to start this one, and my attempts at googling it have come up empty.

Any help is greatly appreciated, even just a link to point me in the right direction would be awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 different Fragments for 3 Tabs using a **(`TabLayout` + `ViewPager`)** combo.
Then call this in the `Activity` that has access to this `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`, then add the tabs dynamically with the custom listviews. There you go, a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your same `CustomAdapter` to populate any data that you want. So, instead of hardcoding the data in your `CustomAdapter`, you can set the data dynamically during object creation.

This way, when you create the `Adapter`, you pass the data that it must handle. Since your activity knows which expandable list item was clicked, you can send different data to your adapter.

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private String [] dataToBePopulated;

    public MyCustomAdapter(String [] data) {
        dataToBePopulated = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataToBePopulated != null ? dataToBePopulated.lenght : 0;
    }

    // ETC..
}
```

Then, when you create the adapter, you can send the data that you want like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);

        ....

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ID_OF_LISTVIEW);
        MyCustomAdapter listViewAdapter;
        if(/* CONDITION 1 */) {
            listViewAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(new String[] {"Data1 for Condition 1", "Data2 for Condition 1", "Data3 for Condition 1"})
        } else if (/* CONDITION 2 */) {
            listViewAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(new String[] {"Data1 for Condition 2", "Data2 for Condition 2"})
        } else {
            listViewAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(new String[] {"Data1 for Condition 3"})
        }

        listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

        ....            
    }

}
```